# Cannot pass TextField to Label on next scene in SceneBuilder

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, scenebuilder

Having issues sending data from one scene to another scene.

The name is grabbed from the MySQL database. I want the name from the Textfield "user_label" to show up in Label "Welcome_User" on the next scene. Please advise and let me know if you need more information.

The error I am getting is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1862)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1729)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8889)
    at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:203)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:208)
    at javafx.controls/com.sun.javafx.scene.control.inputmap.InputMap.handle(InputMap.java:274)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:247)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:234)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.base/javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3856)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene.processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1851)
    at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2584)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:409)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:299)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$2(GlassViewEventHandler.java:447)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:412)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:446)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:556)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:942)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:78)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at com.sun.javafx.reflect.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:76)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor2.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.reflect.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:273)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.MethodHelper.invoke(MethodHelper.java:83)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "sample.HomeController.setName(String)" because "homeController" is null
    at sample.Controller.Login(Controller.java:54)
    ... 57 more
```

Main

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        Scene login = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(login);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
package sample;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;

import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.*;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class Controller {
    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "Database";

    static final String USER = "Username", PASS = "Password";

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    @FXML
    TextField user_label, password_label;
    @FXML
    Label Welcome_user;

    @FXML
    public void Login(ActionEvent event) throws SQLException {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String name = user_label.getText();
            String password = password_label.getText();
            String sql = "SELECT * FROM `login` WHERE Users_name = '" + name + "' AND Password = '" + password + "'";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            if (rs.next()) {
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
                Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home_manager.fxml"));
                Stage homeStage = new Stage();
                Scene scene = new Scene(home);
                homeStage.setTitle("Home");
                homeStage.setScene(scene);
                HomeController homeController = loader.getController();
                homeController.setName(user_label.getText());
            } else {
                System.out.print("Not in Database!");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

HomeController

```
    package sample;

    import java.awt.*;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.sql.*;
    import java.util.ResourceBundle;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.xml.transform.Result;
    
    import javafx.fxml.*;
    import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;
    import javafx.scene.Parent;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.Label;
    import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
    
    public class HomeController {
        @FXML
        Label Welcome_User;
    
        @FXML
        public void setName(String name) {
            Welcome_User.setText("Welcome " + name);
        }
    }
```

home_manager.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
    
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="861.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F98B88;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <Button layoutX="835.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="X" textFill="WHITE" />

    <AnchorPane prefHeight="124.0" prefWidth="126.0">
        <Label layoutX="29.0" layoutY="74.0" text="FSIMS">
            <font>
                <Font size="25.0" />
            </font>
        </Label>

        <ImageView fitHeight="69.0" fitWidth="68.0" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="14.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
            <image>
                <Image url="@cartoon-shoes-transparent-2.png" />
            </image>
        </ImageView>
    </AnchorPane>

    <AnchorPane layoutX="123.0" layoutY="186.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="616.0">
        <Button layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Product Locations" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Sales Orders" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutX="432.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Purchase Orders" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Check Stock" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Receive Goods" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Manage Stocks" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutX="432.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="SKU Generator" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
        <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Ship Goods" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
    </AnchorPane>

    <Button layoutX="749.0" layoutY="470.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Logout" textFill="#fcfcfc" />

    <Label layoutX="382.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="HOME" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true">
        <font>
            <Font size="33.0" />
        </font>
    </Label>

    <Label fx:id="welcome_user" layoutX="665.0" layoutY="27.0" text="Label" />
</AnchorPane>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to declare your controller class in `home_manager.fxml`.

Update your root element as

```
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity"
 minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="861.0"
 style="-fx-background-color: #F98B88;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1"
 xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.HomeController">
```

Notice the new `fx:controller` attributed at the end. This needs to point to your controller class.

---

@Slaw is spot on with his analysis. In addition to missing the `fx:controller` attribute, you instantiated a new `FXMLLoader` instance called `loader`

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
Parent home = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("home_manager.fxml"));
```

but used the `FXMLLoader.load()` static method instead. Hence, the `loader.getController()` method returns `null`.

You need to `load()` using the instance method as

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("home_manager.fxml"));

Parent home = loader.load();
HomeController homeController = loader.getController();
```

Comment: Same problem. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @EricBrown You're getting your controller instance from an `FXMLLoader` instance you did not call `load()` on. You are mixing instance and static methods here. The `FXMLLoader#load(URL)` method is a static method. You need to set the location on the `loader` instance and then call `loader.load()` (an instance method).

Comment: Thank you @Slaw for your comment. I've updated the answer to illustrate your points with code.

Answer (score 2):

You have several problems.

1. File *home_manager.fxml* does not contain `fx:controller="sample.HomeController"`
2. `fx_id="Welcome_User"` (also in file *home_manager.fxml*) This does not match the name of the variable in class `HomeController`.
3. You create a `FXMLLoader` (in method `Login` of class `Controller`) but you don't use it to load file *home_manager.fxml*. Hence calling method `getController()` returns null and that is the error you are getting. By the way @Slaw indicated this in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629384/cannot-pass-textfield-to-label-on-next-scene-in-scenebuilder/68629871#comment121289019_68629871) to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68629384/cannot-pass-textfield-to-label-on-next-scene-in-scenebuilder/68629871#68629871) from Ravi.

I couldn't find file *login.fxml* in your question so I simply added a `Button` to class `Main` together with the event handler from your `Controller` class. I also assigned some arbitrary text to `user_label` in class `Main`.

Class `Main`
(Notes after the code.)

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    TextField user_label;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        user_label = new TextField("George");
        Button button = new Button("Login");
        button.setOnAction(event -> {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("home_manager.fxml"));
            try {
                Parent home = loader.load();
                Stage homeStage = new Stage();
                Scene scene = new Scene(home);
                homeStage.setTitle("Home");
                homeStage.setScene(scene);
                HomeController homeController = loader.getController();
                homeController.setName(user_label.getText());
                homeStage.show();
            }
            catch (IOException xIo) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(xIo);
            }
        });
        Group root = new Group(button);
        Scene login = new Scene(root, 100.0d, 100.0d);
        primaryStage.setScene(login);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

- Class `FXMLLoader` has a constructor that accepts a URL.
- Method [getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) (in class `java.lang.Class`) returns a URL.
- Method `load` (in class `FXMLLoader`) throws `java.io.IOException`. Since I call method `load` in a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), I wrap it in an [unchecked exception](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html).
- Consider using [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html), for example `userLabel` rather than `user_label`.

File *home_manager.fxml*
(Compare with yours.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="520.0" prefWidth="861.0" style="-fx-background-color: #F98B88;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.HomeController">
   <children>
      <Button layoutX="835.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="X" textFill="WHITE" />
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="124.0" prefWidth="126.0">
         <children>
            <Label layoutX="29.0" layoutY="74.0" text="FSIMS">
               <font>
                  <Font size="25.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <AnchorPane layoutX="123.0" layoutY="186.0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="616.0">
         <children>
            <Button layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Product Locations" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Sales Orders" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutX="432.0" layoutY="2.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Purchase Orders" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Check Stock" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Receive Goods" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Manage Stocks" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutX="432.0" layoutY="80.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="SKU Generator" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
            <Button layoutX="216.0" layoutY="160.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="184.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Ship Goods" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
      <Button layoutX="749.0" layoutY="470.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="36.0" prefWidth="98.0" style="-fx-background-color: #800000;" text="Logout" textFill="#fcfcfc" />
      <Label layoutX="382.0" layoutY="107.0" prefHeight="49.0" prefWidth="98.0" text="HOME" textAlignment="CENTER" underline="true">
         <font>
            <Font size="33.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Label fx:id="welcome_user" layoutX="665.0" layoutY="27.0">
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Class `HomeController` is unchanged.

Note that when I ran the above code I got the following exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field javafx.scene.control.Label sample.HomeController.welcome_user accessible: module jfxprjct does not "opens sample" to module javafx.fxml
```

In order to fix that I added the following [java] command option.
(Note: `jfxprjct` is the name of the module that I created for this application.)

```
--add-opens jfxprjct/sample=javafx.fxml
```

Refer to [Five Command Line Options To Hack The Java Module System](https://nipafx.dev/five-command-line-options-hack-java-module-system/)

When I run the code I initially get this window.

[image: Main]

After clicking the *Login* button, I get this window.
(Note the *Welcome George* in the top right corner.)

[image: Home]